# Pandas and adding column and data to a table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datatables

Any idea how to add the division(j) to each row?? I run the program and it runs through each division (division 1 through 5).  I want to add what division it is to each row. I have the headers 'Name, Gender, State, Position, Grad, Club/HS, Rating, Commitment, Division' at the top of the table.  Right now I don't know which division each row is because it is blank.  Thanks for your help....

```
import pandas as pd

max_page_num = 10 

with open('results.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:  
    f.write('Name, Gender, State, Position, Grad, Club/HS, Rating, Commitment, Division\n')

def division():
   for j in range(1,5):
      division = str(j)  
      for i in range(max_page_num):  
         print('page:', i)
         graduation = str(2020)
         area = "commitments" # "commitments" or "clubplayer"
         gender = "m" 
         page_num = str(i)
         source = "https://www.topdrawersoccer.com/search/?query=&divisionId=" + division + "&genderId=m&graduationYear=" + graduation + "&playerRating=&pageNo=" + page_num + "&area=" + area +""
         all_tables = pd.read_html(source)
         df = all_tables[0]
         print('items:', len(df))

         df.to_csv('results.csv', header=False, index=False, mode='a') 

division()
```

Comment: Do you mean df['division'] = division ?

Comment: Hi misantroop: I want to add the school's division i.e. 1,2,3,4, or in a column called "division" in the table in the csv (results.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding the column 'division' should do it if I understand correctly.

```
import pandas as pd

max_page_num = 10 

with open('results.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:  
    f.write('Name, Gender, State, Position, Grad, Club/HS, Rating, Commitment, Division\n')

def division():
   for j in range(1,5):
      division = str(j)  
      for i in range(max_page_num):  
         print('page:', i)
         graduation = str(2020)
         area = "commitments" # "commitments" or "clubplayer"
         gender = "m" 
         page_num = str(i)
         source = "https://www.topdrawersoccer.com/search/?query=&divisionId=" + division + "&genderId=m&graduationYear=" + graduation + "&playerRating=&pageNo=" + page_num + "&area=" + area +""
         all_tables = pd.read_html(source)
         df = all_tables[0]
         df['division'] = division
         print('items:', len(df))

         df.to_csv('results.csv', header=False, index=False, mode='a') 

division()
```